# Difference in converted dates windows and mac

Tags: javascript, json, windows, date, timezone

I found out that on a mac my script is acting different than on a windows. On both systems i am using chrome as the browser, i don't know how to explain my problem properly so ill show you. Below the Javascript function it converts a json time to a javascript date.

```
function getDateFromJSON(value) {
   var retvalue = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
   return retvalue
}
```

When i use this function with a json date string on a windows pc as shown bellow the output is: **Sat Oct 22 1988 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)**

When i use the same function with a mac the output is: **Fri Oct 21 1988 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CEST)**

The code i used on both mac and windows is:

```
console.log(getDateFromJSON("/Date(593474400000)/"));
```

Can someone please help me explain how i can fix this?

Comment: The timezone name in parentheses comes from the operating system, and there's no common standard for that. Why is that a problem?

Comment: The other difference is that the two machines have different timezone settings. They're one timezone apart.

Comment: im developing a web application and some customers are using mac, and dates are changing like in the example: Mac substracts on day from the original when this user save's, the date has changed. (no one noticed at first)

Comment: It's not subtracting a day. 23:00 Friday in CEST is the same time as 00:00 Saturday in WEDT.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Mac vs PC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both dates are the same (after adjusting for timezones)

If you want to standardize, use `toUTCString`:

```
> new Date(" Sat Oct 22 1988 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)").toUTCString()
'Fri, 21 Oct 1988 22:00:00 GMT'
> new Date("Fri Oct 21 1988 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CEST)").toUTCString()
'Fri, 21 Oct 1988 22:00:00 GMT'
```

Comment: The time i am hoping to get is the european, so is there a way to convert the mac time (cest) to (w. Europe Daylight Time)?

Comment: @Josef32 if you want to force western european daylight time, you can either adjust the times by adding an offset (add 2 hours to the time, then call toUTCString and replace GMT with `(W. Europe Daylight Time)`) OR use a proper library like https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

Comment: Thanks all for your help, the problem was that chrome on a mac doesn't recognize daylight saving time. The solution of Nirk to use timezone.js worked.

Comment: @Josef32 - That's just blatantly false. Chrome on a mac absolutely *does* recognize daylight saving time.